# Objective-C: How to Make Float from Long Int Value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I save latitude and longitude values of a map point as integer in my database.

So my values are like: 3454534353. But when using, I need to use a float as 34.54534353.

How can I make this conversion?

Here's how I create map point:

```
MapLocation *location = [[MapLocation alloc] init];  
location.title = [NSString stringWithString:[locations objectForKey:@"title"]];  
location.subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:[locations objectForKey:@"subtitle"]];  
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;   
coordinate.latitude = // need a float like xx.xxxxx  
coordinate.longitude = // need a float like xx.xxxxx;  
location.coordinate = coordinate;  
[annotations addObject:location];  
[mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: float f = (float)intvalue / 10000000.0f;        is that ok?

Comment: so it is. please post an answer, I'll mark as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moved the comment to answer

```
float f = (float)intvalue / 10000000.0f;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to divide your integers (used as, in fact, fixed point numbers) by the appropriate power of ten represented as a true `float`:

```
float long_float = longitude / 10000000.0f;
```